# How to move image continues vertically using canvas in android?

Tags: android, canvas

I wanted to move image vertically using the canvas? i have tried below things but it's not working....

```
canvas.translate(200, 0);
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapGrass, 0, 0, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

*You should post some more info on what it is that won't work.*
**However**, in your case you could just skip the `canvas.translate()` as the transformation is so simple. You code would be something like:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapGrass, 200, 0, null);
```

Comment: Actuall i wanted to move the image vertically automatically. so i draw bitmap on canvas, now i want it to move continuously..

Comment: If you only want it to move horizontally/vertically you can do that with the drawBitmap() method, no need to move the canvas.